# Showing error message in form for Nested forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I have a form which uses nested resources and for some reason no error messages are appearing like they do in my other forms.

**This is my form:** (in short)

```
<%= form_for(@order, url: listing_orders_path([@listing, @listing_tweet]), remote: true) do |form| %>

<% if @order.errors.any? %>
 <ul>
   <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <%= msg %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

 <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :twitter_link, "Twitter Link" %>
  <%= form.text_field :twitter_link, class: "form-control", required: true  %>
 </div>

   <% form.hidden_field :order_type, value: 2 %>

   <%= form.submit %>

<% end %>
```

**order.rb model:**

```
  validates :twitter_link, format: { with: /\A((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?twitter.com\//,
    message: "use a valid twitter url" }
```

The validation itself is working, just the message won't appear.

**Question:** How do I correct my html or any other code to have the error message appear?

The idea is that if a URL doesn't include or begin with twitter.com, they error message should appear.

---

I used this exact error code in other forms but the only difference is that this form is using nested resources.  So I have tried doing things like

if @order([@listing, @listing_tweet]), etc (other combinations similar) but none allow the page to load.  I would assume @order should work fine because that's where the submit goes

As an explanation to the possible duplicate.... My error message for the validation ISN'T appearing at all.  The "possible duplicate" question is in reference to the order of their error messages.

**I will show below where my code works, and then after, where it doesn't work [with the nested resources]**

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for([@listing, @listing_tweet]) do |form| %>
   <% if @listing_tweet.errors.any? %>
      <ul>
        <% @listing_tweet.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <%= msg %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="field col-10">
      <%= form.text_field :price, class: "form-control"  %>
      <%= form.label :price %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="actions col-2">
      <%= form.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success"  %>
    </div>


    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Listing tweet model:**

```
validates :price, :numericality => {:only_integer => true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 5, message: "must be great than or equal to $5" }
```

The above code generates an error message when the text_field input isn't validates

The difference between this and the form I have issues with is that it is a double nested form.  Not sure how to explain other than "double nested" but you can see the difference above.

Both create methods in the controllers use this formatting:

```
else
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

---

UPDATE:

I was thinking it may be an issue with my create method since I use valid? before initiating my charge code nd after ray mentioned it...

**Here's my create in short:**

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    #more code here


        if @order.valid?
          begin

            ###stripe code here to create charges

          rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            charge_error = e.message
          end
          if charge_error
            flash[:error] = charge_error
            redirect_to listing_path(@listing)
          else


        respond_to do |format|
          if @order.save
            @order.update_column(:order_status, 1)
            if user_signed_in?
              # @user = current_user
              # OrderMailer.order_email(@user, @order).deliver
              format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
              else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Any issues in the create method to cause the validates error message to not appear?

Comment: inspect `<%= @order.errors.full_messages %>` in view and check whether error message present or not

Comment: hm.  I searchd for "full_messages" and nothing came up

Comment: Then I am sure, @order is not validated in action by `valid?` or save methods (save, update_attributes etc). You need to provide your  code of action called

Comment: I saw this in ror guides 
`>>p = Person.new 
   # => #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
   >> p.errors.messages
   # => {}
    >> p.valid?
    # => false
    >> p.errors.messages
    # => {name:["can't be blank"]}
   >> p = Person.create
    # => #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
    >> p.errors.messages
    # => {name:["can't be blank"]}`

Comment: so you need to call valid? or save methods after creating model objects

Comment: @ray Code of action.. can you clarify.  Do you mean the en.yml ? or the controller code?

Comment: @BhargavReddy I'm only looking for the error from the validates to show up.  It's separate than the create or update methods in the controller --- as I said, I have used this same code elsewhere for validates error message but the only difference is, this is a nested resource.  And I don't understand why the message won't appear.

Comment: @ray On the page where this code works on another form... the "full_messages" doesn't show up either.  Not sure if that's the issue anymore.  I can only assume its' the html as of now unless someone has another opinion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show nested form validation errors after the validation errors for the parent model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181303/how-to-show-nested-form-validation-errors-after-the-validation-errors-for-the-pa)

Comment: @wasipeer I updated my OP.  If you see a reason for how it's a duplicate, please let me know.

Comment: @ray It actually is possible this is an issue with my create method in my orders controller.  I'm going to post it in the end of my OP at the bottom.  because I use valid? to create charges .

Comment: What I know is  'save' method also generates error messages in the model object if the object  is not valid, I think that might be the problem

Comment: Something is disturbing the validates error message from appearing.